# CMake on GitHub Action with Googletest

Tags: c, cmake, github-actions

### Introduction

Currently, I'm working on a C project with CMake and Googletest.
My project is on a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/Piscine-42).

Why I execute the test on my local machine I use this command: `cmake -B ./build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`. It works.

```
@MathieuSoysal ➜ /workspaces/Piscine-42 (main) $cmake -B ./build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /workspaces/Piscine-42/build
```

### Problem

And I'm trying to execute it on GitHub Actions. But it does not work.

##### The Log

```
Run cmake -B /home/runner/work/Piscine-42/Piscine-42/build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
  cmake -B /home/runner/work/Piscine-42/Piscine-42/build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    BUILD_TYPE: Release
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    /home/runner/work/Piscine-42/Piscine-42/googletest

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/runner/work/Piscine-42/Piscine-42/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

### Question

Does someone know how we can execute this command `cmake -B /home/runner/work/Piscine-42/Piscine-42/build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` on GitHub Actions with a linked GitHub repo?

Comment: I think you are missing a `with: submodules: recursive` in your `actions/checkout@v3` (thus GitHub Actions is not checking out the `googletest` folder, and CMake Error complains about not being able to find it). Have a look at this other action doing apparently the same as you are trying to do: https://github.com/selyunin/gtest_submodule/blob/master/.github/workflows/cmake.yml

Comment: @rturrado That is it, thank you. It works with your suggestion.